# Are there any other vedic ritual other than yajnas?

Tags: vedas, vedic-rituals

[Samhita](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samhita) is the ritualistic part of the Vedas. There must be many rituals in the Samhita.

So are there any other vedic ritual other than [yajnas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yajna#:%7E:text=Yajna%20Sanskrit%3A%20%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%9C%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9E%3B%20IAST,Brahmanas%2C%20as%20well%20as%20Yajurveda.)

Comment: I think, *Yajna* is an umbrella term. It covers all kinds of rituals and sometimes activities. Even the process of conceiving a child has been called a sacred yajna in the *vedas*.